# OOP setting a property through a method within the class?

Tags: php, oop, properties

New to OOP, the idea is to instantiate an object in a class passing two properties in the process and using a method within the class to generate a third property that i would later need to use.

Does this make sense in OOP terms? I would have thought that my dostuff method would create my thirdproperty ready for use for my next methods in the class?

Here's my code:

```
<?php
class Nameofclass {

public $firstproperty = '';
public $secondproperty ='';
public $thirdproperty ='';


public function __construct ($firstproperty, $secondproperty) {

$this->firstproperty = $firstproperty;
$this->secondproperty = $secondproperty;
}

public function dostuff($firstproperty) {
do a lot of clever stuff here to calculate a $value;
$this->thirdproperty = $value
}

}
$newInstance = new Nameofclass('firstproperty', 'secondproperty');
echo $newInstance->thirdproperty;
?>
```

What am I doing wrong? My var_dump($newInstance->thirdproperty) returns Null - as initially set i suppose.... slightly confused here?!

Comment: If the value of `thirdproperty` is only set by `dostuff()` then you need to call `dostuff()`... unless you call it in the constructor, it won't call itself

Comment: Thanks Mark! Could I call dostuff() in the constructor then?

Comment: there's no reason why you shouldn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want thirdproperty to be set, then you need to call `dostuff'.  One way to accomplish this would be to modify your constructor slightly:

```
public function __construct ($firstproperty, $secondproperty) {
    $this->firstproperty = $firstproperty;
    $this->secondproperty = $secondproperty;
    $this->dostuff($firstproperty);
}
```

However, you're missing out on one of the benefits of using OOP by passing that parameter.  Instead, you could rewrite dostuff as so:

```
public function dostuff() {
    // use $this->firstproperty here, since youve already set it instead of passing it into the function
    do a lot of clever stuff here to calculate a $value;
    $this->thirdproperty = $value;
 }

 // Then, your call to dostuff in your constructor could look like this (without the parameter)

public function __construct ($firstproperty, $secondproperty) {
    $this->firstproperty = $firstproperty;
    $this->secondproperty = $secondproperty;
    $this->dostuff();
}
```

Of course, this all depends on how you intend to use `dostuff`.

Comment: Thanks Cale_b! Works fine! Still have a lot to learn on this constructor or so it seems!

Comment: @Guillaume or simply to learn that a function will not be called if you don't call it :)

Comment: @RoyalBg indeed! Now that the __construct calls is for me it should be easier!!! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you change this

```
public function __construct ($firstproperty, $secondproperty) {

$this->firstproperty = $firstproperty;
$this->secondproperty = $secondproperty;
}
```

to

```
public function __construct ($firstproperty, $secondproperty) {

$this->firstproperty = $firstproperty;
$this->secondproperty = $secondproperty;
$this->doStuff()
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sephedo! Newbie to OOP as mentioned! Very simple it was!